# Reload corrupted definition or attribute

Tags: python, matplotlib

Suppose I made this mistake:

```
plt.xlabel='Longitude'
```

How would I correct this mistake so that the following code works:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  
t = np.arange(-180.0, 180.0, 0.1)
s = np.radians(t)/2.
  
plt.plot(t, s, '-', lw = 2)
  
plt.xlabel('Longitude')
plt.ylabel('Latitude')
plt.grid(True)
  
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Force reloading of the module: `importlib.reload(plt)`